# Video file being saved by OpenCV is corrupt

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

```
The following code snippet is used to save a video file using OpenCV:

from multiprocessing import Process
from .streams import InputStream
from .camera import *
import cv2
import imutils
import logging
import time
import os
import numpy as np
import skvideo.io

log = logging.getLogger('igate')

class RecordWorker:

  def __init__(self, camera, config):
    self.config = config
    self.process = Process(target = self.save, args = (camera, ))


  def start(self):
    self.process.start()
    return self


  def save(self, camera):
    log.debug(f'{camera.id} RecordWorker SAVE started')
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
    videofile_count = self.get_start_videofile_number()
    video_filepath = self.config['video_save_path'] + camera.view + '_' +  f'{videofile_count:03d}' + '.avi'

    log.info(f'Saving video: {video_filepath}')
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(video_filepath, fourcc, 25.0, (640,360), True)          
    #writer = skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter(video_filepath + '.avi')

    while True:
      frame, index = camera.inputStream.read()
      if frame is not None:
        log.info("got frame...");
        video_writer.write(np.uint8(255*frame)) 
    camera.inputStream.stop()  
    video_writer.release()  

  def get_start_videofile_number(self):
    return 2
```

The problem is the file that is saved in the output location is corrupt, it is of size 6 KB and doesn't contain any content(looks like no frame was read initially). Can someone help me out with what might have gone wrong here?

Comment: Are you executing `save` in a separate process? With the `camera` object passed to that process? What type is `camera`?

Comment: @M.Spiller, the save() method is indeed coming from a different process(class) with the camera object being passed to that process, and camera is another class that outs together the real specifics of the camera that is used in this setup such as resolution, fps etc. Let me know if you need any other details.